# Photon emission rate frequency dependency

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, frequency

I am puzzling over the dependence of the energy flux of electromagnetic radiation on the frequency of the source.

1. The power radiated in any direction or solid angle from a charged particle oscillating harmonically at frequency $\omega$ according to [the classical electrodynamics $\propto\omega^4$](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_32.html#Ch32-S2).
2. The energy carried by a photon according to quantum mechanics $\propto\omega$.

Does that imply the number of photons per unit time emitted in any direction from the charge $\propto\omega^3$?

Comment: Notice that the formula in Feynman depends also on $x_0$. Free particle oscillating in external EM field will have $x_0 \propto \frac{1}{\omega^2}$, so the Larmor power actually does not depend on frequency at all, only on the EM wave amplitude, $e$ and $m_e$ (Thomson scattering regime). Only in atoms/molecules there is a good argument for why $x_0$ may be sort of the same for all frequencies (transition electric dipole moment elements in QT do not depend on frequency).

Comment: @JánLalinský: Just saw this above. I suppose $x_0\propto\frac1{\omega^2}$ comes from the Lorentz-Drude model e.g. Equation (32.15) or (32.16) of https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_32.html#Ch32-S5. But those and Equation (32.17) show that the energy flux $P$ is a function of $\omega$, and moreover $\propto\omega^4$ for $\omega_0\gg\omega$. So the question still stands.

Comment: Yes, if the electron is bound and frequency of the primary EM wave is low enough below the resonance, Larmor's power depends on frequency as $\omega^4$. This is the regime of the Rayleigh scattering.

Comment: Interpreting this classical result in terms of photons indeed leads to "number of photons per second" proportional to $\omega^3$, but notice the result is valid also for very low frequencies (radio frequencies, quasi-static changes of electric field), where the photon language is not usual/appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, assuming the mechanical displacement of the charged particle is fixed, yes. I am, however, finding it hard to think of a real radiation process where the mechanical displacement is independent of frequency.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148599/discussion-on-answer-by-john-doty-photon-emission-rate-frequency-dependency); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.